# How do I make a PageView wrap back to its first page?

Tags: flutter

How can I connect the first and last pages of a `PageView`, so that you can keep swiping infinitely to change pages? I want something like this, but that would work with the swipe gesture:

```
void changePage(bool left) {
    if (_numPages == null || _numPages < 1)
      return;
    var duration = Duration(milliseconds: 100);
    var curve = Curves.easeInSine;
    int page = _pageController.page.round();
    page = left ? page - 1 : page + 1;
    page = page % _numPages;
    _pageController.animateToPage(page, duration: duration, curve: curve);
}
```

Comment: You are using `Pageview.builder` ?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede I was using the regular constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PageView default has infinite scroll, just don't provide itemCount:

```
PageView.builder(
      controller: pageController,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return PinchZoomImage(
          image: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            child: imageList[index],
          ),
        );
      },
```